# Error thrown in OKHttpClient version 3.2.0 using SPDY version 3

Tags: android, rest, spdy, okhttp

I have an application that uses:

```
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp:2.7.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okhttp3:okhttp-urlconnection:3.2.0'
compile 'com.squareup.okio:okio:1.6.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:retrofit:2.0.0'
compile 'com.squareup.retrofit2:converter-gson:2.0.0-beta3'
```

And makes API REST calls to a server. When enabling SPDY 3 on the OKHttpClient, an error is thrown:

```
04-08 11:01:22.321 10628-10628/dts W/System.err: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: protocols doesn't contain http/1.1: [spdy/3.1, h2]
04-08 11:01:22.321 10628-10628/dts W/System.err:  at okhttp3.OkHttpClient$Builder.protocols(OkHttpClient.java:672)
```

I can't find anything on OKHttpClient correctly enabling SPDY/3 or the error code. The destination site has SPDY/3 configured correctly.

I have tried both protocol configs with all combos of SPDY3, HTTP/2 & HTTP/1, application works when HTTP/1 is configured, but throws error if SPDY/3 only is enabled:

```
okHttpClient = new OkHttpClient.Builder()
                    // .protocols(Collections.singletonList(Protocol.SPDY_3))
                    .protocols(Arrays.asList(Protocol.SPDY_3, Protocol.HTTP_2))
                    .retryOnConnectionFailure(true)
                    .connectTimeout(25, TimeUnit.SECONDS)
                    .connectionPool(new ConnectionPool(30, 120, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
                    .connectionSpecs(Collections.singletonList(spec))
                    .addInterceptor(new AddCookiesInterceptor())
                    .addInterceptor(new ReceivedCookiesInterceptor())
                    .cache(new okhttp3.Cache(cacheLocation, (500 * 1024 * 1024)))
                    .build();
        }
```

I know someone may have ideas, any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: I did find this in the docs [link](https://square.github.io/okhttp/2.x/okhttp/com/squareup/okhttp/OkHttpClient.html) but with no help on configuring SPDY/3:     Parameters:
protocols - the protocols to use, in order of preference. The list must contain Protocol.HTTP_1_1. It must not contain null or Protocol.HTTP_1_0.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, the newest version of OKHttp dropped support for SPDY/3. The error code is thrown when selecting only proto SPDY or HTTP2. The documentation notes that HTTP1 is always required as a proto, and additional selections after. Switched over to HTTP2 with Android 4.1 and you'll find further connection issues (OKHttp/Android) doesn't support TLS1.2 out of the box, you'll have to create a custom SSLSocketFactory to override the defaults (from [here](https://gist.github.com/fkrauthan/ac8624466a4dee4fd02f)):

```
public class TLSSocketFactory extends SSLSocketFactory {

private SSLSocketFactory delegate;

public TLSSocketFactory() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException {
    SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
    context.init(null, null, null);
    delegate = context.getSocketFactory();
}

@Override
public String[] getDefaultCipherSuites() {
    return new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"};
}

@Override
public String[] getSupportedCipherSuites() {
    return new String[]{"TLSv1.2", "TLS_RSA_WITH_AES_128_CBC_SHA"};
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(Socket s, String host, int port, boolean autoClose) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(s, host, port, autoClose));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(String host, int port, InetAddress localHost, int localPort) throws IOException, UnknownHostException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port, localHost, localPort));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress host, int port) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(host, port));
}

@Override
public Socket createSocket(InetAddress address, int port, InetAddress localAddress, int localPort) throws IOException {
    return enableTLSOnSocket(delegate.createSocket(address, port, localAddress, localPort));
}

private Socket enableTLSOnSocket(Socket socket) {
    if (socket != null && (socket instanceof SSLSocket)) {
        ((SSLSocket) socket).setEnabledProtocols(new String[]{"TLSv1.2"});
    }
    return socket;
}
```

}